# Proof that the electric field in a dielectric decreases by a factor

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, polarization, vector-fields

We have a linear homogeneous dielectric material half filling a parallel plate capacitor. It's said that the field inside is  reduced by a factor ,so we have
$\mathbf 
  {E}=\frac{1}{\epsilon_{r}} 
  \mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{vac}}$.

What's its proof?
( If anyone tries to prove it using the similaritiy of $E$ and $D$ ,I think that is incorrect due to non zero curl of $D$ in this case) .
[image]

Comment: This might help: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/dielec.html

Comment: You can't prove it, because it's simply not true in general. It just happens to be true in sufficiently symmetric situations.

Comment: @knzhou,  I'm referring to this particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gauss Law suggests that  $ \nabla . D = \rho $. When there is no charge in a defined boundary. Ingoing and outgoing $D$ are equal. In your case, there are no charges outside of electrodes, thus, there will be no change of $D$ along the paths between the electrodes. Since $D = \epsilon_r . \epsilon_0 . E$ .  As a result, the electric field will depend on the $\epsilon_r$ to keep $D$ constant.

Comment: Thanks, however I think to prove this,  you have assumed the field to point downwards, everywhere inside the capacitor. Is it so? If yes, then how do you justify it?

Comment: You are right! The uniform field is due to the assumption of the uniform distribution of the charges across the plates and the assumption of infinite plates. If the plates are finite, there will be leakage of the electric field and the field will be more non-uniform to the sides. **Intuitively**, I can say that if you follow the Gauss Law at any boundary point where no charges exist, there will be no divergence of the field. Only the field magnitude will be scaled related to the epsilon_r, keeping the direction not changed. _I would appreciate if someone proves or disproves my claim._